# Why isn't the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ the universal cover of $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The question is very simple, i think. But i cannot see the answer.
The fact is that a universal cover has a fiber which is isomorphic (under a choice of a point) to the fundamental group of the covered space. In this case $\mathbb{R}$ whit the exponential map has this property, while $I$ with the exponential map not. But actually it is a covering, is simply connected and so by definition also *the* universal cover.

Where is the flaw in this (paradoxal) argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$I$ with the exponential map is not a covering.  Indeed, let $p\colon I\to S^1$ be continuous and take some small neighbourhood $U$ of $p(1)$ in $S^1$.  If $U$ is small enough, then it is homeomorphic to an open interval.  But $p^{-1}(U)$ contains, as a connected component, a small neighbourhood of $1$ in $I$, and this neighbourhood is homeomorphic to a half-open interval.

Answer (score 5):

While $[0,1]$ is simply connected, the natural projection map $\pi \colon [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ given by $\pi(\theta) = e^{2\pi i \theta}$ (where we think of $S^1$ as the circle in the complex plane $S^1 = \{ e^{i \theta} \, | \, \theta \in [0,2\pi] \}$) is not a covering map. For example, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(1) = \{ 0, 1 \}$ contains two points while every other fiber contains only a single point which can't happen for a cover map.

Comment: In fact, there doesn't any map $f \colon [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ which is a covering map because the possible covering spaces of $S^1$ are $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and they are both not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: * which can't happen for a covering map from a connected covering space, right? I believe this phenomenon is possible for disconnected covers.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to tell that the map is not a covering map is recalling that if the base is connected, then the covering has fibers of the same cardinality, which is clearly not the case (take the fiber at $0$ and at $1/2$).

Yet another way is to use the fact that a compact base space with infinite fundamental group must have a noncompact universal cover (although rather indirect, this also shows that there cannot exist any cover whatsoever $p:I \to S^1$ and is a nice result in itself). One important note is that this *does not* use "uniqueness" of the universal cover, only that we have a covering map from a simply connected space.

Comment: Do you know a reference for this result about (non)compact coverings? Or a proof sketch?

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been well answered, but it seems a shame not to mention an additional fact about the map $p: [0,1] \to S^1, t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$. From it we can obtain the pushout diagram of groupoids, with the top $2$ being discrete groupoids,

$$\begin{matrix} \{0,1\} & \to & \{0 \}\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
\mathbb I & \xrightarrow{p} & \mathbb Z  
\end{matrix}$$ 
where $\mathbb I = \pi_1([0,1],\{0,1\})  $  is the fundamental groupoid on two base points $0,1$. This groupoid has $4$ arrows, including $\iota: 0 \to 1$, and with $\iota$ is a **generator** for the category of groupoids, as $\mathbb Z$ with $1$ is for the category of groups. (That is, an arrow $g$ of a groupoid $G$  is completely determined by a morphism $g': \mathbb I \to G$ such that $g'(\iota) = g$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Fun Fact** $:$ Let $p : \widetilde X \longrightarrow X$ be a covering map and $x_0 \in X.$ Let $X$ be path-connected and $\widetilde X$ be simply-connected. Define a map $$\Phi : p^{-1} (x_0) \times \pi_1 (X, x_0) \longrightarrow p^{-1} (x_0),\ \ (e,[\gamma]) \mapsto e \cdot [\gamma] = \widetilde \gamma_e (1)$$ where $\widetilde \gamma_e$ is the unique lift of $\gamma$ starting at $e \in p^{-1} (x_0).$ Then $\Phi$ defines a well-defined right group action of $\pi_1 (X, x_0)$ on $p^{-1} (x_0)$ which is free and transitive. Consequently, by the virtue of orbit-stabilizer theorem it follows that the degree of the covering is $\left \lvert \pi_1 (X, x_0) \right \rvert.$

This is a quite straightforward thing to prove. Well-definedness follows directly from the homotopy lifting property, freeness and transitivity of the action follows respectively from the facts that $\pi_1 \left (\widetilde X \right ) = 0$ and $\widetilde X$ is path-connected, both of which hold as $\widetilde X$ is assumed to be simply-connected.

**How does that help here?** $:$

**Claim** $:$ There does not exist any covering map $p : [0,1] \longrightarrow S^1$ of finite degree.

If it is not the case then since $[0,1]$ is simply-connected and $S^1$ is path-connected it follows from the above fact that the degree of the covering map $p$ is same as $\left \lvert \pi_1 (S^1) \right \rvert = \left \lvert \mathbb Z \right \rvert = \infty,$ a contradiction to the hypothesis.

In your case $p$ is the exponential map and hence $p^{-1} (1) = \{0, 1 \},$ which is a finite set and consequently it cannot be a covering map.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody mentioned the main property of a [covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Properties) so far: A covering map is a local homeomorphism.

Assume that $p: I=[0,1]\to S^1$ is a covering map. Then, there is an open set $U=[0,\epsilon)\subset I$ such that $p|_U:U\to p(U)$ is homeomorphism, $p(U)\in T_{S^1}$. This is not possible: Let $V=p(U)-\{p(0)\}.$ Then $V$ is disconnected open set. But, $(p|U)^{-1}(V)$ is connected, contradicting the continuity of $p|U$.

Comment: I think there is no boundary of $p(U)$ since it is open.

Comment: $p$ is surjective.

Comment: There is a nbd of $p(0)$, an open arc, whose preiamge is $[0,\epsilon)$ and its disoint translates. So, V is disconnected.

Comment: Why $1$? There is nothing special about $1$ here.

Comment: $p(x)=\exp(3\pi i x)$ is surjective and $p(0)\neq p(1)$.

Comment: My apologies. The entire time, I thought you were discussing $p(x)=\exp(2\pi ix)$, rather than treating a general covering map. So most of my comments were irrelevant and I've retracted them. However somebody (the accepted answer) *did* already mention local homeomorphism. Your own argument needs more work, it's not true for *all* opens sets $X$ of $S^1$ that $X\setminus\{x\}$ (for some point $x$) is disconnected.

Comment: @FShrike I will think about the improvement.  Thank you for discussion. I just didnt see the word "local " in any answer. That is what surprised me.